# How to create input group using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create an input box group like the following:

```
title1

name: (input text box)
link: (input text box)

remove this title

title2

name: (input text box)
link: (input text box)

remove this title
```

And my css is

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><h3>title1</h3></label>
    <label for="inputError" class="control-label">name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="field span6" type="text" id="newsLinkTxt_1" />
    </div>
    </br>
    <label for="inputError" class="control-label">link</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="field span6" type="text" id="newsLink_1" />
    </div>
    </br>
    <button class="btn" id="removeButton" type="button">remove this</button>
 </div>
```

The problem is the control-label class will have margin 20 , so the input box will have left margin 20 . However the title1 and the button will align to left, what class should I use for button and the heading in a control-group , or I need to have customized css? Thanks

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out the .form-group or .input-group sections

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: can you not use the .form-group class then further modify any other tweaks

Comment: You should not just post links as links may die, please spell out what the necessary steps are and/or provide sufficient info for an answer in case the link becomes obsolete

Answer (score 0):

can you not use the .form-group class then further modify any other tweaks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: but the answer above me is ok? it was acccepted and up voted and says the same

Comment: It is subtlely different in that links were provided, your answer is a question which does not direct answer the question, merely asking why they did not try a particular method. The OP is free to upvote and accept an answer, even though the answer is ill-formed (in this case link only answers are frowned upon), I will comment on the answer above. Hope this clarifies things